# Jquery Popover - Hide

Tags: jquery, popover

I have strange problem. I made popover in Jquery. When it appears some links are behind it. When I close it i cannot click this links. It's like this popover is hidden and we cannot see it but it's still there end it's blockin 'way' to this links...

My script for closing popover:

```
    $(document).on("click",".close", function(){
        $("#add-users-from-emails-btn").popover('hide');
    });
```

Popover:

```
    $("#add-users-from-emails-btn").popover({
        placement: "bottom",
        title: '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button> {{'user.index.enter_users_emails_each_rows'|trans|raw}}',
        html: true,
        content: $("#add-users-from-emails-popover")
    }).on('show.bs.popover', function(){
        $("#add-users-from-emails-popover").removeClass("hidden");
    }).on('shown.bs.popover', function(){
        $("#add-users-from-emails-popover textarea").focus();
    });
```

Form:

```
<form id="add-users-from-emails-popover" class="hidden clearfix" style="width: 300px;" method="post" action="{{path('adm_user_addusersfromemails')}}">
    <select name="business" class="form-control">
        <option class="empty" value>{{'empty_value'|trans({},'app')}}</option>
        {% for b in business %}
            <option value="{{b.id}}">{{b.businessName}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <textarea name="emails" style="margin-top: 10px" rows="5" class="form-control" style="max-width: 300px;"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" style="margin-top: 10px" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right" id="save-users-from-emails-btn">{{ 'user.index.add_users'|trans }}</button>
</form>
```

What Am I doin wrong ? ;-)

PROBLEM SOLVED
Correct script for closing popover:

```
    $(document).on("click",".close", function(){
        $("#add-users-from-emails-btn").click();
    });
```

Comment: without seeing the popover and related code we won't be able to do much... my guess will be there is a transparent overlay over the close button

Comment: How is the class .hidden defined?  You're doing display:none, not visibility:invisible, right?

Comment: Yep, it's display none. But i solved the problem after Arun P Johny comment. I just didn't make popover hide but click function, like that:             $(document).on("click",".close", function(){
                $("#add-users-from-emails-btn").click();
            });